Software IP stolen - options?
I need some advice. I had been working as the sole developer on a SaaS business for nearly a year with 2 other business cofounders. I signed a contract that stipulates 2 things:

a cofounder can be expelled with or without cause if it’s a majority decision
all IP belongs to the company

And they basically screwed me over, took my code and now I have nothing except for the code I have built. I’m wondering what are my options here, because based on the contract it’s obviously clear cut: nothing and move on.
However I had a text from a cofounder that literally says this in a WhatsApp message:
“X said he did get the code to the source code from the database.
He also has an agency in India that has done countless tech projects, streamlined that will get everything done in a timely fashion for $40/hr with management and supervisors. US-based tech companies have used them.
But he said he’s a god fearing man and is not unethical, so he could’ve taken the source code that he has and not paid you, but he’s willing to pay you whether you continue or don’t continue. I think I still have a chance to convince X to keep the original agreement in place, but I have to know you’re going to 100% commit to this. Let me know before the end of the day because X wants to conclude this project ASAP.”
Note: I didn’t get paid a penny. I asked for 20k, and that was a more than fair price.
Am I cooked? Obviously I don’t want to have worked for free for 12 months, so based on the above sketchy message, could I still sell the platform to another company based on “unlawful termination” or no?(well, the message basically says they stole my work)

You signed a contract where you're the only one doing the real work and the two other cofounders can kick you out any time and take your work.... why exactly?

Jesus why all the downvotes? Came here asking for help. Anyway, it’s bc I thought I could prevent them from accessing my code - ever

Downvotes because you're asking for a legal advice, which is off-topic. So you thought you could screw them, and they screwed you instead? Karma...

What the heck, u asked why did I sign. That’s the answer. I thought I could protect my IP. How is that trying to scam them?

But it's not yours. You said you signed a contract that assigns all rights to the company. You need to talk to an employment lawyer about the payment.

What did the contract specify as your "consideration"? Usual considerations would include salary, fixed payments, stock etc.

It was an all equity agreement (15% share)

being fired does not prevent you from owning 15% of the company.

Questions asking for specific legal advice are off-topic here. This site is not an alternative to hiring a lawyer.


because based on the contract it’s obviously clear cut: nothing and move on.

Then those are your legal options.
We cannot make up any other options for you, given that we don't even know your specific contract, only your understanding of it. Based on your summary, you signed a hideously bad contract and the other party executed exactly what was in it. "But that's so unfair" is not really a legal principle. In many countries, you can sign many of your "fair" rights away and it seems you did.
Considering contracts are tricky beasts and depending on your juristiction there might be legal minimums and defaults to consider even if not explicitely mentioned in the contract, you may want to dicuss your actual contract with an actual lawyer in your juristiction.
Maybe you are missing an option and a lawyer can show it to you. Good luck.

Well what about the cofounder’s message that basically says “we considered stealing your code and that’s exactly what we are going to do”?

I don't see how anything has been stolen from you, the source code never belonged to your in the first place, it belonged to the company you have been expelled from. At least based on what you said. Given that that is only your understanding, it is better to show all your legal documents to a real lawyer, instead of playing chinese whispers with internet people. Find a professional and let them have a look.

Well, maybe because I had been fired for a made up reason? So that they get to keep 15% of the equity?

Well, you said they did not need cause... again, consult a lawyer in your juristiction.

This is US. Also, just bc the contract says with or without cause, doesn’t mean they can just fire me and keep my work. There is such a thing as wrongful termination right?

it seems to me that if they did not have the code they could sue to get it.

That wasn’t the question. They got the code. And I don’t have my equity anymore as they made up an excuse to fire me. They also sent me a message implying this (“could have fired you and not pay you but they are “ethical””)

Firing you means exactly that: getting rid of you, but keeping your work. Do you think if they fire a factory worker at Ford, he gets to take all the cars he built?

@D.Richard, you are arguing with strangers over the terms of a private contract that none of us have read. It seems your expectations are unrealistic - both on this site, and in your personal circumstances.  Read the contract, read it again, then consult a lawyer if you think you have a case.
